# Tweaking Phonegap´s app execution performance

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, cordova

I am been building a various amount of PhoneGap Apps, and i run into the same problem everytime.

They dont run that fast, to be honest.  The task of collecting 5 rows from the internal database is slow.  Im talking seconds slow.

The issue is not the code, i have tried with phonegap´s own testing codechunks from their site.  Its a really simple code.

So i am running my phonegap development environment command promt wise.  I install Node.js, ran the npm install -g phone commands and so forth.  I have no eclipse.

What i can do is to fix my config.xml file, and edit it.

This has been mentioned in some threads and questions i read so far.  But these i am not sure, dosent look like a config.xml fix, or some random JS for my index.html file.

- Adding android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in the manifest If you use
- webview webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
- and webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

I am looking for a way to "enhance the performance of the app".

So far i havent been lucky on my google searches, actually i havent found any solid solutions yet.  That might be that i dont know the correct search words.

Other than:

- Optimizing my Javascript
- Only enable what i need in the config.xml file
- Make sure to use optimized images

What did i miss?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using Phonegap version 3?

Comment: hmm well i thought that if i dident use the phonegap-version in my config.xml the default version would be 3.0.  When i look on my build.phonegap.com it do say 2.9.0.  Even tho that the documentation say that the default is 3.  Is there sort of documentaion on phonegaps version 3 that its running fasteR?

Comment: i will try this, and i will make a comment back when i am done.  :-)  thanks in advance.